# Bypass 2 step verification of Amazon Seller Account

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, one-time-password, amazonsellercentral

I have an amazon seller account and I want to `__scrape__` all the information of orders from it using scrapy.

But 2 step verification is enabled on my account.

I have tried to disable it but again amazon asked me to enable 2 step verification to access it.

In 2 step verification, amazon send me OTP on my phone number, so after sign In, I have to enter OTP code.

Is there any way to avoid this?

One way is to develop some mobile application which will read the OTP and save it on some DB from where my script can read it.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking at the same thing, the only solutions can think of are:

1. Use Twilio to receive the sms https://www.twilio.com/ and fill that field (is going to cost you each time you log in)
2. Use a python autentificator app such https://pypi.org/project/authenticator/
3. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gawk.smsforwarder&hl=en&gl=US use this to forward your sms to email, then read the codes with python

Try them and let me think if the work because I'm working at the same thing.